# How to update column in one table based on row values from a different table?

Tags: sql, oracle

How is my dummy table look like

```
            Table1                                                    Table2
UsrId  Name   Class   Prof               UsrId   Name   Class   Prof    XYZ     ABC
1      Sinch    2       Y                  1     Sinch    2       Y    some text in here
2      Moira    6       N                  2     Moira    7       N    some text in here
3     Camelia   8       Y                  3    Camelia   8       N    some text in here
4      Cannon   3       Y                  4     Cannon   3       N    some text in here
5      Pauley   2       Y                  5     Pauley   1       Y    some text in here
6      Rhodes   4       Y                  6     Rhodes   4       Y    some text in here
7      Allen    6       Y                  7     Allen    6       Y    some text in here
8      Guerrero 8       Y                  8     Guerrero 8       N    some text in here
```

I have two tables Table 1 and Table 2, How can we update the row of Table2 except column XYZ and ABC and update the other cell if there is a difference based on Table1
like for UsrId 2 Class and Prof is has updated value in Table 1  but not in Table 2 so how can we perform update operation here. Is it possible to perform such operation

Any hep will be apprecited thanks you .

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` seems to be simple enough to do that.

```
merge into table2 b
  using table1 a
  on (a.usrid = b.usrid)
  when matched then update set
    b.name = a.name,
    b.class = a.class,
    b.prof = a.prof;
```

Comment: @Lottlefoot, I am in new will it be an efficient query if I have a 100K record

Comment: What makes you think that it wouldn't be efficient?

Comment: Actually i will using the query in spring boot JPA application so was asking

Comment: I don't know anything about *spring boot JPA*, but - as far as Oracle is concerned - MERGE works just fine & fast.